# SQL Query, latest rows for each unique duo

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have to do a sql query and I don't know how to do. I'd like to get the latest rows for each unique duo A/B. I'm working with postgresql.

For instance:
Table: Person

```
id  A  B  modification_date
1   5  6  2014-04-12
2   6  7  2014-04-13
3   5  6  2014-04-14
4   9  1  2014-04-15
5   6  7  2014-04-16
```

And I'd like to get:

```
id  A  B  modification_date
3   5  6  2014-04-14
4   9  1  2014-04-15
5   6  7  2014-04-16
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why is `5  6  2014-04-12` in the expected result? The "latest" (i.e. "newest" row for 5/6 should be `5  6  2014-04-14`, shouldn't it?

Comment: You are right a_horse_with_no_name, i corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` the `MAX`imum of `modification_date` for each `GROUP` of (`A`, `B`), then `JOIN` back to the original row to get the values (necessary to get the `id` column):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Person t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(modification_date) max_date, A, B
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY A, B
) t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B AND t1.modification_date = t2.max_date
```

---

More simply, if you don't care which `id` you get back, and you only want one row even if `modification_date` is duplicated, you can just select the `MIN`imum value of `id` and be done with it:

```
SELECT MIN(id) id, A, B, MAX(modification_date) modification_date
FROM Person
GROUP BY A, B
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b)
       *
FROM   person
ORDER  BY a, b, modification_date DESC;
```

Detailed explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, a, b, modification_date
FROM person p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM person nx
    WHERE nxa = pa AND nx.b = p.b
    AND (nx.modification_date > p.modification_date
         OR nx.modification_date = p.modification_date AND nx.id > p.id)
    );
```